# Why doesn't inotify detect my file deletions on travis-ci?

Tags: travis-ci, inotify

[My tests are failing on travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/fish-shell/fish-shell/jobs/25304252) because inotify is not delivering IN_DELETE or IN_DELETE_SELF events. On other Linux boxes, the code works correctly.

[Here is a sample program](https://gist.github.com/ridiculousfish/a0955206c50cab4bf473) that creates a file, watches it, deletes it, and then looks for an inotify event. This reports "inotify seems OK" on my Linux boxes, but that inotify is busted on travis-ci. No errors are reported - the file descriptor simply never becomes readable.

The kernel version on the travis-ci build is "2.6.32-042stab079.5", while inotify was merged in 2.6.13, so I expect inotify to work.

Is inotify supported on travis-ci? If so, why is my code not working? If not, how can I detect at build time or runtime whether inotify is supported, so I can use another code path?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You'd problaby have better luck with this issue if you [open a bug report with travis-ci](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/new)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know they were on github! I should have looked!

Comment: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2342 for anyone finding this.